# How to model a multi db setup on one host in ansible?

Tags: ansible

**Here is the setup**
Each of the environments have one or many dbserves.
Each dbserver can, but must not, have databases running on different ports. E.g:

server1:port1 -> db1
server1:port2 -> db2
server2:port1 -> db3

I want to insert configuration updates to the databases. The question is now how to model this setup in ansible:

- I can not go by host_vars since the ports are not unique by host
- since I do not know how many db servers I have I would need to have a generic approach (so the option to pass via -e or as role var is not possible)
- I can not use nested loops (e.g. over the ports) since the ports differ

**My workaround**
I came up with a workaround to have groups as like:

dbservers_db1
dbservers_db2

That way I can do the following:

```
- include_tasks: db_config_update.yml 
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['dbservers_db1'] }}"   
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host

- include_tasks: db_config_update.yml 
  with_items:
    - "{{ groups['dbservers_db2'] }}"   
  loop_control:
    loop_var: host
```

Note: this can not be done in ONE loop since ansible would detect the same host and process it only once.

But this workaround has its limitations:

- I need for every further db a new group
- it is not intuitive

**How could this be modeled in a smarter way ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define for each host, which DBs are running on the host.

- `host_vars/host1.yml`:

  ```
  dbs:
    - db1
    - db2
  ```
- `host_vars/host2.yml`:

  ```
  dbs:
    - db3
    - db4
  ```

Then define a task for each host in which you iterate over the dbs of the host:

`playbook.yml`:

```
- include_tasks: db_config_update.yml 
  with_items: dbs
```